# Remove annotations each time the UISlider is moved - mapView, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, uislider, mkannotation

How can I remove annotations "dynamically". That is, for example, if I have a UISlider, every time I move the slider I want to delete some annotations on the map. How can it be done?
(please note, annotations on the map are added to each movement of the slider, but the annotations of the previous step of the slider MUST be deleted).

Answer (score 0):

some more information would be very helpful to generate a more specific answer. But one of the solutions could be like so:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var mapView: MKMapView?
    
    private var myItems: [Item]? {
        didSet {
            clearItems()
            refreshItems()
        }
    }
    
    private var sliderValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            refreshItems()
        }
    }
    
    private func clearItems() {
        guard let mapView = mapView else { return }
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    }
    
    private func refreshItems() {
        guard let myItems = myItems else { return }
        
        let itemsToRemove = myItems.filter { $0.minimumDisplayValue > sliderValue && $0.isShown }
        mapView?.removeAnnotations(itemsToRemove.map { $0.annotation })
        itemsToRemove.forEach { $0.isShown = false }
        
        let itemsToAdd = myItems.filter { $0.minimumDisplayValue <= sliderValue && !$0.isShown }
        mapView?.addAnnotations(itemsToAdd.map { $0.annotation })
        itemsToAdd.forEach { $0.isShown = true }
    }
    
    @IBAction private func sliderMoved(_ sender: UISlider) {
        self.sliderValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    }

    
}

// MARK: - Item

private extension MapViewController {
    
    class Item {
        let annotation: MKAnnotation
        let minimumDisplayValue: CGFloat
        var isShown: Bool = false
        
        init(annotation: MKAnnotation, minimumDisplayValue: CGFloat) {
            self.annotation = annotation
            self.minimumDisplayValue = minimumDisplayValue
        }
    }
    
}
```

In this case you can store all annotations under `myItems`. Then when you move your slider you basically change filter of which of these items are actually shown on the map.

The most of interesting part happens in `refreshItems`. In this case more and more annotations should be shown when you move slider to increasing values. And less annotations when you decrease slider value. Any other logic could be applied in there though.

Comment: I've asked a similar question before, but with some code at this link, just no one answered ... let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64471948/remove-annotation-when-slider-moves-swift